# Renaming multiple directories while keeping a part in the middle with varying suffix

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I'm trying to change the name of multiple directories using bash, the names being structures like the following:

> DRMAD_CA-12__MRBK01_237a8430    DRMAD_CA-17__MRBK10_766c3396
> DRMAD_CA-103__MRBK100_c27a6c1c

The goal is the to keep the MRBK as well as the number following directly after it (`MRBK###`), but to get rid of of the rest. The pattern of the prefix is always the same (`DRMAD_CA-###__`), while the suffix is '`_`' followed by a combination of exactly 8 letters and digits. Tried `sed`, but can't seem to figure out the right pattern.

Seeing other posts on Stackoverflow, I've tired variations of

```sh
ls | while read file; do new=$( echo $file | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([^ ]*\)[^.]*\(\..*\)*MRBK\1\2/' ) mv "$file" "$new" done
```

But since I don't really understand the syntax of sed, it doesn't produce a usable result.

Comment: Please share what you tried to see where the problem is.

Comment: Seeing other posts on Stackoverflow, I've tired variations of 
`ls | while read file; do new=$( echo $file | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([^ ]*\)[^.]*\(\..*\)*MRBK\1\2/' ) mv "$file" "$new" done`
But since I don't really understand the syntax of `sed`, it doesn't produce a usable result.

Comment: Probably, it will be easier with `for f in DRMAD_CA-*; do mv "$f" $(cut -d '_' -f 4 <<< "$f"); done` - get the files starting with `DRMAD_CA-` and split them with `_` and rename with the fourth chunk.

Comment: That gives me following error for a testcase:
`mv: missing destination file operand after 'DRMAD_CA-12____MRBK45_237a8430'`

Comment: Right, so the number of `_` can be any one or more, right?

Comment: It is exactly one after `DRMAD` and after `MRBK##` and exactly two after `CA-##`

Comment: Sorry, but in the one above, you have 4 underscores after `12`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's my bad! It there actually are 4 `_` after the `CA-##`. I've got a working solution below, thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Ok, I think `for f in $(find . -name 'DRMAD_CA-*'); do mv "$f" $(sed -n 's/.*_\(MRBK[0-9]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$f"); done` will work, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does work, thank you so much! This will definitly help me in the future with other uses of `sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` utility.
First, print the old and new names, but do not rename anything:

```
rename --dry-run 's/.*(MRBK\d+).*/$1/' *MRBK*
```

If OK, actually rename:

```
rename 's/.*(MRBK\d+).*/$1/' *MRBK*
```

Install `rename`, for example, using `conda`.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much, this actually worked! Thank you for taking your time, you guys are great.

Answer (score 1):

Using find:

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*MRBK[[:digit:]]+.*$" | while read line
do 
     dir=$(dirname $line)
     newfil=$(grep -Eo 'MRBK[[:digit:]]+' <<< $line)
     mv "$line" "$dir/$newfil"
done
```